# Drag & Drop functionality of jquery/html5 is not supported in windows phone

Tags: html, jquery-ui, windows-phone-7

Drag & Drop functionality of jquery/html5 is not supported in windows phone. How to make it run?
`aria-grabbed` & `aria-dropeffect` property would be helpful for this.
If no. What is solution for this problem?

Comment: If it's not supported, how do you expect it to run?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few other basic things that don't run in Windows Phones. For example,

Like the comment mentions, it's not supported yet. It there were ways to run these things, then it wouldn't be unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is due to lack of mousemove event on IE9/WP7. As a **possible workaround** I would recommend to try [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) since it adds this functionality using special native proxy. Take a look on this vid

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CPaCgHQNrc

PS. On WP8 this should work since IE10/WP8 supports full set of mouse events